# Chrome-har-capturer and Android via ADB

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb, har

I need to use [chrome-har-capturer](https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-har-capturer) with an Android phone via ADB.

With Chrome on the local machine, one can start Chrome with the following switch:

```
--remote-debugging-port=<port>
```

and then use chrome-hat-capturer as below to connect to the specified port for remote debugging:

```
chrome-hat-capturer --port <port>  -o out.har
```

The issue with Android is that while I can start Chrome on Android using ADB, It doesn't accept the remote debugging switch:

```
db shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main --remote-debugging-port=9222

Error: Unknown option: --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else trying to do this, I found how to do this:

On you local machine:

1) Run chrome:

```
adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main
```

2) Forward the debugging port:

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

3) Run chrome-har-capturer:

```
chrome-har-capturer --force --port 9222 -o my.har http://www.example.com
```

Note that you must use the **--force** option.